# how to save and load state of program

Tags: python, multithreading, state, pickle

I have the following code.when I stop execute or close the script, it should save the current execution state in a file. and when I run the script again it should load the previous state first and then do rest of execution that is given in function.

```
def main():
    while True:
        for root, dir, files in os.walk(drive):

                if file in files:
                    a = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(root, file)))

                    if a not in list1:
                        list1.append(a)
                        print(list1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

how can implement pickle or dill?

Comment: Make a dictionary with the current root and dir and the list for values; pickle it;add logic/code to unpikle and use it at startup.

Comment: pickle can save values in variables but not running loop. After restart you would have to load values and run loop and `os.walk()` again and skip files until you get the same root, dir, file.

Comment: pickle is probably the wrong approach here - you should save the list of files you've already gone through in a file or a database of some sort. BTW - what would you like to happen if new files are added to the system between the first execution of the script and the second one?

Comment: please make `list1` a set

Answer (score 0):

There is no convenient tool for that.

You have to write a save/load feature for yourself.

For example, you can save your progress to a local file, and load it when the script runs again.